# Will a small C: partition (SSD) slow down my PC?

Tags: windows-10, ssd

I just installed Windows 10 onto an SSD and I was wondering how best I should partition it. With hard-disks, we would want a large C: drive since it sits on the inner most part of the hard-disk. How does it work with SSDs?

Presently, I've partitioned by 250 GB SSD like this:

- C: 58 GB (System)
- D: 58 GB
- E: 51 GB
- F: 40 GB
- 40 GB on unallocated Space

Should I increase the allocation for the C: drive? I like to segregate my programs into different drives for organization and I usually don't install anything on the C: drive at all unless the program can only go on the C: drive.

Additionally, will programs load faster if I put them in C: drive considering that this is a SSD? I'm guessing not -- but I still want to see if I'm missing something.

Comment: The size of a partition on a disk has zero effect on the performance of the disk.  SSDs are significantly faster then mechanical HDDs.

Comment: What's the goal of those partitioning at all, in global? In most cases either single partition or 2 partition (OS, Data) scheme is optimal.

Comment: @Akina -- I just like to use different drives exclusively for different purposes.

Comment: What is the goal of unused 40Gb slack rest? Will you move from C: to another partition: pagefile/hiberfil? temporary folders? user profiles? *will programs load faster if I put them in C: drive considering that this is a SSD?* No.

Comment: *how best I should partition [my drive]*...there is no correct answer to this question and as such is not a good fit for the Q&A format of this site.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, partitioning has more importance on mechanical hard drives because the data is stored on one or more physical platters with the data arranged in tracks, from the inner-most track 0 out to near the edge of the platter.

Partitioning limits the physical area needed to be searched and limits the physical distance the heads have to travel to find the needed data.

With SSDs, everything it accessible immediately with no limitation of physical arrangement, eliminating the need to partition in the same way as an HDD. However, because of the nature of SSDs, it is often advised to save some unused, unpartitioned space in reserve should a few cells in the flash chips fail (much like bad sectors on HDDs).

The partition scheme you outlined should have no real performance impact, access wise. Depending on features installed and where you put your user files, you may wish to increase the size of C, simply for then extra space.

Comment: "it is often advised to save some unused, unpartitioned space in reserve should a few cells in the flash chips fail (much like bad sectors on HDDs)." Very good idea.

Comment: Keeping unpartitioned space in SSDs is pointless. SSDs already over-provision their space, with the higher-end drives having even more "spare" space for the purpose of replacing failed addresses. It is not necessary to leave space in the partition table because the drive has already accounted for this, and the drive controller handles this itself, transparently to the OS and the user.